# Linear Algebra Matrices and bases

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an assignment question that I am having some hard time working out and would appreciate any help understanding and solving this please. Here is the question

Given the linear transformation:
$$T([x,y,z]) = [x+y,x+z,y-z]$$

Find the matrix representation $A_1$ and $A_2$ with respect to the bases
$$B_1 = \{[1,1,1],[1,1,0],[1,0,0]\}$$
$$B_2 = \{[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,1]\}$$

and find a matrix $P$ such that
$$A_1 = P^{-1}A_2P$$

Comment: What have you tried? Part (a) should just be a matter of plugging in definitions. Have you made any progress on attempting to do that?

Comment: At least, for $B_2$ it should be just plug-and-chug.

Comment: Its not getting into my mind. Can you please help hoe to get in to these, please?

Answer (score 1):

Given a base $\mathcal B = \{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ of some vector space $V$, and a linear transformation $T : V \to V$, the representation matrix is the matrix whose $i$-te column are the coefficients of the image of the $i$-basis vector under $T$. More formally if
$$
 Tv_i = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ji} v_j
$$
for $i = 1,\ldots, n$, then the matrix of $T$ with respect to $\mathcal B$ is
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
  a_{11} & a_{12} & \ldots & a_{1n} \\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & \ldots & a_{2n} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \ldots & a_{nn}
 \end{pmatrix} = ( \vec{a_1} \quad \vec{a_2} \quad \ldots \quad \vec{a_n} )
$$
where the vector $\vec a_i$ collects the coefficients of the $i$-th basis vector. Applying this directly to (a) you see that
$$
 T([1 ~ 1 ~ 1]) = [2, 2, 0] = 2\cdot [1,1,0] = 0 \cdot [1~1~1] + 2\cdot [1,1,0] + 0\cdot [1,0,0]
$$
so the first column of your matrix must be $[0,2,0]$. I guess you can work out the rest from here?

For (b) you need to find the transformation matrix for a change of a basis, this is precisely the representation matrix of the identity transformation with $\mathcal B_1$ in the source space, and $\mathcal B_2$ in your destination space (I just talk about the representation matrix above for the case that the basis is the same in both spaces, but indeed they could be different and the definition just remains the same, you collect the coefficient w.r.t. your basis in the destination space). So with the above you have to write each vector of $\mathcal B_1$ as a linear combination of vectors from $\mathcal B_2$ and collect the coefficients in the columns of the matrix. And then check that the resulting matrix fulfills the equation you wrote, if you get stuck just write up  or ask here again.

Remark: I defined the representation matrix as collecting the coefficients in the columns, that what I most often encounter. But sometimes people do it in the rows, so you have to look how you do it in your lectures! The result differs by matrix transposition then.

On request I supply an **example for part (b)** for the two bases
$$
 \mathcal B_3 = \{ [1 ~ 0 ~ 0], [0 ~ 1 ~ 0], [0 ~ 0 ~ 1] \}
$$
(this is your base $\mathcal B_2$ but with a different ordering on the basis vectors, which is of course by an abuse of notation written as a set, but should be a sequence) and
$$
 \mathcal B_4 = \{ [1~2~3], [0~1~0], [0~1~1] \}.
$$
Then the representation matrix of $T$ in base $\mathcal B_3$ (as computed by Dustan Levenstein) is
$$
 A_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & -1 
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and as
$$
\begin{array}{lclcl}
 T([1 ~ 2 ~ 3]) & = & [3 ~ 4 ~ -1] & = & 3\cdot [1~2~3] + 8\cdot[0~1~0] - 10\cdot[0~1~1] \\
 T([0~1~0]) & = & [1~0~1] & = & 1\cdot [1~2~3] + 0\cdot [0~1~0] - 2\cdot [0~1~1] \\
 T([0~1~1]) & = & [1~1~0] & = & 1\cdot [1~2~3] + 2\cdot [0~1~0] - 3\cdot [0~1~1] 
\end{array}
$$
the representation matrix in base $\mathcal B_4$ is
$$
 A_4 = \begin{pmatrix}
  3 & 1 & 1 \\
  8 & 0 & 2 \\
  -10 & -2 & -3
 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now to find a matrix $Q$ such that $A_4 = Q^{-1}A_3Q$ I start to write the vectors of $\mathcal B_4$ as linear combinations of vectors from $\mathcal B_3$, and as this is the canonical basis this is quite easy (these are precisely the numbers in the coordinates then). I put these coefficients in the columns of the matrix $Q$ and get
$$
 Q = \begin{pmatrix} 
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   2 & 1 & 1 \\
   3 & 0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}.
$$
And we have
$$
 Q^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & -1 \\
  -3 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
and $A_4 = Q^{-1}A_3Q$.

Comment: Thanks a million. Can you please help me with (b) part. It would be great if you please explain with an example

Comment: I put up an example with two different bases.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just address part (a), with the use of $B_2$, to help you understand definitions. Unfortunately there is no single definition of the matrices, so you may need to adapt your answer accordingly if you're writing this up for a homework assignment; this is just in terms of the definition I learned. (I don't mean to imply that the definitions are inconsistent with each other; there are just different ways of defining the same matrix.)

Let $v_1= [1,0,0]$, $v_2=[0,1,0]$ and $v_3=[0,0,1]$, so that $B_2 = \{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$. We evaluate $$T(v_1) = T([1,0,0]) = [1,1,0] = v_1+v_2,$$ $$T(v_2 = T([0,1,0]) = [1,0,1] = v_1+v_3,$$ and $$T(v_3) = T([0,0,1]) = [0,1,-1] = v_2-v_3.$$

The column vectors associated to these, with respect to the basis $B_2$, are given by the coefficients of $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$ in order:

$$T(v_1) \leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, T(v_2) \leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}, \text{ and } T(v_3) \leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}.$$

The matrix of $T$ with respect to $B_2$ comes from simply putting these three column vectors together, in order, into the columns of a matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: You just represented $T$ with respect to the canonical basis in $\mathbb R^3$, not the given basis?

Comment: $B_2$ is the canonical basis.

Comment: Ah, sorry I just looked for $\mathcal B_1$ in my answer, but right yes $\mathcal B_2$ is the canoncial basis :)

Comment: The original poster refused to do the work in the easy case, so I figured they must need help understanding the definitions.

Comment: Yes, I also just posted a definition and worked out one single column of the matrix, the rest is up to him.

Comment: agreed. ${}{}{}$